# Unknown reason why the frequency spectrum of a "knocking force" (impulse) gets some spike

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum

During my experiment (vibration analysis), I deliver a knocking force from a shaker (and the shaker itself has an impulse or an half-sine wave signal). The system automatically calculates with the FFT algorithm and gives me the following graph for the input force signal. Note that I was investigating different parameters, and this is not the proper experiment yet. Though the input signal would be probably kept the same for the main experiment.

[image]

My question is that: why do we spikes here, in the frequency spectrum?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What's you x-axis? time or frequency ? what are the units ?

Comment: Is 50Hz your local power line frequency?

Comment: @Hilmar x-axis is frequency, and it's in Hz

Comment: @TimWescott Yes, the local frequency is 50 Hz. But I don't think it is the reason. I do not measure the AC here

Comment: If you're measuring something that's high-impedance, has a lot of area, is low-level, or is connected to big power -- yes, you're measuring the local AC there.  You pretty much cannot avoid measuring your local AC, unless you hike out to the wilderness with a bunch of battery-powered equipment.  Grab an oscilloscope, touch the probe, and look -- you'll see that you're measuring AC.

Comment: Here, the signal is dervied from a force sensor attached on a shaker. Both the force sensor and the shaker are connected to their individual control box, and both boxes are connected to the grid (or "plug in the socket"). With the power frequency at 50 Hz, it would lead to a "spike" of 50 Hz here, yes? Then how about 150, 350 and 450? And for reference, I repeat the same experiment today, and I change the position of the shaker a bit, I see a spike at 250 Hz. What is the reason for these spikes? Is it still because of the 50 Hz powerline?

Thanks